# Warning where I cannot clear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an error saying Incompatible pointer types sending NSArray to parameter of NSString. I also have used instruments and is very weird that as soon as my app start its around 90mb in memory.  What is wrong with my code.

```
@interface TrashViewController ()

@end

@implementation TrashViewController {
    NSMutableArray *Trash ;
}
@synthesize collectionTrash;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    filenames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *locations = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Bottoms", @"Dress", @"Coats", @"Others", @"hats", @"Tops",nil ];
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:locations];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    collectionTrash.delegate =self;
    collectionTrash.dataSource=self;
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent)
    {
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        [filenames addObject:finalFilePath];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    NSLog(@"j");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [filenames count];


}



- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ReuseID";
    TrashCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageInCell = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    NSString *cacheKey = filenames[indexPath.item];
    imageInCell.image = [self.imageCache objectForKey:cacheKey];

    if (imageInCell.image == nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filenames[indexPath.item]];
            if (image) {
                [self.imageCache setObject:image forKey:cacheKey];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    TrashCell *updateCell = (id)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    UIImageView *imageInCell = (UIImageView*)[updateCell viewWithTag:1];
                    imageInCell.image = image;
                });
            }
        });
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"s:%d", [Trash count]);
    NSString *trashBin = [Trash objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"k%@l",trashBin);
    [filenames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [Trash removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self deleteMyFiles:trashBin];
    [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]];
}
NSString *myFileName;
-(void) deleteMyFiles:(NSString*)filePath {
    NSError *error;

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
    }
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    [self.imageCache removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you failed to include the exact error message in your question, and you also failed to identify the line in error.

Answer (score 1):

eYour problem is in line 5 of viewDidLoad. The method signature for -stringByAppendingPathComponent is

```
- (NSString *)stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString *)aString
```

Note that it expects a String, but you are passing an Array.

What you probably want to do is change

```
NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:locations];
```

To something like

```
NSInteger someIndex = 0; //this will pick the first object in locations, e.g. @"Bottoms".
NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[locations objectAtIndex:someIndex]];
```

locations is an Array of Strings, so you need to pick one and not pass the entire Array.

Also, next time please dont just dump your code in here, but tell us which line caused the error. You are much more likely to get a quick response if you can point to the part that couses the problems.

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering I don't get the someIndex I have changed the NSString that was in viewdidload to the thing directed and getting an error undeclared identifier someIndex. Also I do not get the first line of code. What am I suppose to write under it?

Comment: @user3001507 - The first line is just the method signature, taken from the docs. Dont implement it in your code. And of course you need to declare someIndex at some point before using it. it should just be an integer between 0 and 4, referencing an object in your locations-array

Comment: @user3001507 - i added an example for declaring someIndex